# Python csv column math

Tags: python, list, math, csv

I am trying to automate converting large .txt files to .csv for importing in dedicated software. What I have is dozens of .txt files containing very large strings with comma separated sensor data:

```
Date,Time,[Mainline] Name,MAG4 Altitude Value,IL MAG1 Easting,IL MAG1 Northing,Magnetic Field MAG1 [uT] Value,Magnetic Field MAG1 [uT] Quality,MAG1 Depth Value,IL MAG2 Easting,IL MAG2 Northing,Magnetic Field MAG2 [uT] Value,Magnetic Field MAG2 [uT] Quality,MAG2 Depth Value,IL MAG3 Easting,IL MAG3 Northing,Magnetic Field MAG3 [uT] Value,Magnetic Field MAG3 [uT] Quality,MAG3 Depth Value,IL MAG4 Easting,IL MAG4 Northing,Magnetic Field MAG4 [uT] Value,Magnetic Field MAG4 [uT] Quality,MAG4 Depth Value,IL MRU Pitch,IL MRU Roll
25-9-2013,27:48.6,INF_01,464,579618.04,5807421.24,49008.96,2212,18.68,579616.64,5807420.71,49003.14,1284,18.73,579615.23,5807420.18,49005.78,1428,18.97,579613.83,5807419.65,48999.99,1382,18.99,4.68,-0.14
25-9-2013,27:49.1,INF_01,461,579618.35,5807420.4,49008.99,2197,18.68,579616.95,5807419.88,49003.01,1270,18.73,579615.54,5807419.35,49005.73,1416,18.97,579614.14,5807418.83,49000.01,1379,18.83,3.66,0.23
25-9-2013,27:49.3,INF_01,461,579618.49,5807420.07,49008.9,2192,18.68,579617.08,5807419.55,49003.13,1255,18.73,579615.68,5807419.02,49005.6,1416,18.97,579614.27,5807418.5,48999.73,1377,18.99,3.14,0.31
```

What I need is to convert this to a .csv file with the header, and separate the information for each sensor. 
For the first sensor (mag1) I need columns 0,1,2, 5 to 8, then 3 and finally 24 and 25. For the second sensor, columns 0,1,2, 9 to 13, then 3 and 24 and 25. The same idea for the other sensors.

I've got a bit of code that succesfully converts the file to the four separate products that I need. However; what I'd like to do is convert the data in column 3 using the formula value = value*0.0101817 - 1.0283.

Code:

```
import csv,glob,os

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:/test/*.txt')

for filename in list_of_files:
    short_filename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    file_out_mag1 = short_filename + '_mag1' + ".csv"
    file_out_mag2 = short_filename + '_mag2' + ".csv"
    file_out_mag3 = short_filename + '_mag3' + ".csv"
    file_out_mag4 = short_filename + '_mag4' + ".csv"

with open(filename,"r") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open(file_out_mag1,"w") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result,lineterminator='\n' )
        for r in rdr:
            #r.strip() ->does not work, list has no attribute strip
            #r.split(',') -> does not work, list has no attribute split
            if r ==3:   #does not work?
                r = r*0.0101817 - 1.0283
            wtr.writerow( (r[0],r[1],r[2],r[4],r[5],r[6],r[7],r[8],r[3], r[24], r[25]) )

with open(filename,"r") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )  #this line had to be added again        
    with open(file_out_mag2,"w") as result: #does not work, file empty, solved see above
        wtr= csv.writer( result,lineterminator='\n' )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow((r[0],r[1],r[2],r[9],r[10],r[11],r[12],r[13],r[3], r[24], r[25]) )


with open(filename,"r") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )          
    with open(file_out_mag3,"w") as result: 
        wtr= csv.writer( result,lineterminator='\n' )
            for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow((r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3],r[14],r[15],r[16],r[17],r[18],r[3], r[24], r[25]) )

with open(filename,"r") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )          
    with open(file_out_mag4,"w") as result: 
        wtr= csv.writer( result,lineterminator='\n' )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow((r[0],r[1],r[2],r[19],r[20],r[21],r[22],r[23],r[3], r[24], r[25]) )
```

The math formula doesn't work in my program. How do I add this to my code and why does it not work here? I'm assuming it is because it is the wrong type but I don't know how to change that without running into a series of errors about list type etc.

I've browsed stackoverflow and the python documentation but I'm stuck. The examples I've found only show working with text strings, not numerical values and strings.
If anyone can point me to a good tutorial for working with scientific data like this, I'd be grateful.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Please explain what is not working.

Comment: Try to isolate your problem: Does the CSV parsing work? If no, fix it. If yes: does the math work? If not, fix it *without* using CSV for input.

Comment: The row `r` is a list, not a string. Strip and split both apply to strings. If you want to adjust a specific column, you can use something like `r[column_num] = r[column_num] * magic_number - other_magic_number`.

Comment: Also, you should really call out what's wrong in the question text, not as comments in your code. It makes it easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The csv parsing works, I get output files containing the relevant columns. What is not working is the math formula I added. I'll try thegrinner's advice and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to thegrinner's advice, I solved this:

```
with open(filename,"r") as source:
rdr= csv.reader( source )
with open(file_out_mag1,"w") as result:
    wtr= csv.writer( result,lineterminator='\n' )
    for r in rdr:

        if r[3] != 'MAG4 Altitude Value':
            r[3] = float(r[3])*0.0101817 - 1.0283
        wtr.writerow( (r[0],r[1],r[2],r[4],r[5],r[6],r[7],r[8],r[3], r[24], r[25]) )
```

I'm still new to programming, so are there ways to improve the coding?

Comment: My advice about the code is to organize it so that the major parts of the problem are separated. For example you could organize it like this: First read the csv file without doing any string to number parsing or other processing. Then parse all the numbers. Then apply the math formula to create a new array containing the numbers for output (do not write the results into the original array, just leave it alone). Then write the output array into the output file. I think you'll find that breaking the solution into independent parts makes it easier to comprehend your program.